# Mandrill methods not showing up

Tags: php, mandrill, email-templates

I have added Mandrill's api to my project via composer, and I have also installed it manually(not at the same time). I'm trying to use a template that I created in my Mandrill account. I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with my code. Even if there is, it's not causing the problem that I'm having. The problem is the Mandrill methods aren't showing up. When I type

```
$mandrill->
```

... these are my following choices:

```
$apikey,
$ch,
$debug,
$root,
_destruct() - Mandrill,
call($url, $param) - Mandrill,
castError($result) - Mandrill,
log($msg) - Mandrill
```

Now, I'm not sure what all the methods are suppose to be. I do know that one of the methods is suppose to be messages. If anyone can give me some trouble-shooting ideas, it would be greatly appreciated. I've been at it for 6 hours now.

I should note, when I created the object, I had to use a forward slash in order for my project to find it...

```
     $mandrill = new \Mandrill('my api key');
```

I only bring this up because I didn't see this being done on every single example that exist out in the web.

Thanks in advance,

Chris M.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html . Its has PHP library specific examples of each API, like for example:

```
$result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async, $ip_pool, $send_at);
```

Hope this helps,